# How to get one document instead having multiple with the same name nodejs mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am working on nodejs mongodb RESTful APIs.I have 10 object documents(works that electrician can do) with the same category name(electrician).I need to get that category name in just one object one time but when i query then all 10 documents shows up with just category name.how can i get just one object instead having 10 with same category name.

There are 10 objects like given below with same category name.

```
{ "category": [ { "_id": "5b80393f7fca491488980fe1", "category_name": "electrical", "sub_category_name": "switches meters and fuses", "price": 300 }] }
```

But when i query i get

```
{"category": [ { "_id": "5b80393f7fca491488980fe1", "category_name": "electrical" },{ "_id": "5b80393f7fca491488980fe1", "category_name": "electrical" }] }
```

Comment: {
    "category": [
        {
            "_id": "5b80393f7fca491488980fe1",
            "category_name": "electrical",
            "sub_category_name": "switches meters and fuses",
            "price": 300
        }]
}

Comment: But when i query i get

Comment: {"category": [
        {
            "_id": "5b80393f7fca491488980fe1",
            "category_name": "electrical"
        },{
            "_id": "5b80393f7fca491488980fe1",
            "category_name": "electrical"
        }]
}

Comment: Can you paste the query you're using?

Comment: router.get('/name', async(req,res)=>{
    const c = await Category.find()
        // .select('category_name');
        res.send({
            category: c
        });
});

Comment: i am using just find query

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your expected output correctly, you can use [`aggregate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) in place of your *`find`* to do what you want.

[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) takes the query [[1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/q5F4Tt7IK0E)]:

```
{ $match: { "category.category_name": 'electrical' }},
```

[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) will flatten the *category* array [[2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gS7dWnzA8BT)]:

```
{ $unwind: '$category' }
```

[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) allows us to group by the *category_name* and make an array out of the individual documents in each group [[3](https://mongoplayground.net/p/V9ywZ5jrgPj)]:

```
{ 
    $group: { 
        _id: { category_name: '$category.category_name' },
       category: {
            $push: {
                _id: '$category._id',
                sub_category_name: '$category.sub_category_name',
                price: '$category.price'
            }
       }
    }
}
```

[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to get the *category_name* out of *_id* [[4](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YRF8RSQJRrs)]:

```
{ 
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        category_name: '$_id.category_name',
        category: '$category'
    }
}
```